# 'copy-item' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have problem with this:

> 'copy-item' is not recognized as an internal or external command

How can I fix it?

```
system ("start powershell  get-Childitem -Path 'D:\Program Files\12' -recurse -filter *.dxf | copy-item -Destination 'C:\22'")
```

Comment: No.  'Copy-Item' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Is robocopy on the machine? That would handle the copy in one call : "robocopy /s 'D:\Program Files\12'  'C:\22' *.dxf"

Comment: what happens if you just type in `copy-item` into a powershell window?

Comment: @Blaze Powershell commands are case insensitive

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with C++ - you will encounter the same problem if you enter that in a cmd window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is because you are running the entire string `"start powershell  get-Childitem -Path 'D:\Program Files\12' -recurse -filter *.dxf | copy-item -Destination 'C:\22'` as a single command.

What its doing is running the command `start powershell  get-Childitem -Path 'D:\Program Files\12' -recurse -filter *.dxf` first and then running `copy-item -Destination 'C:\22'` after the command has run. Now `copy-item` obviously doesn't exist in CMD so it throws an error.

You will need to wrap the string `get-Childitem -Path 'D:\Program Files\12' -recurse -filter *.dxf | copy-item -Destination 'C:\22'` in quotes so that the entire string is given to powershell to run.

As a simple example, the command `start powershell Get-ChildItem | write-output` fails, but the command `start powershell "Get-ChildItem | write-output"` works as intended.